# Replacing the close() function in Linux with my own close() function

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ld-preload

I'm trying to provide my own implementation of the `close()` function in Linux. Why? Because I just found out you could do that and it sounds fun.

Here's myclose.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int close(int fd) {
    printf("Closing fd: %d\n", fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my makefile:

```
all: myclose.so my-close.so

%.so: %.o
    gcc -shared -o $@ $<

%.o:%.c
    gcc -c -fPIC -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.so *.o
```

After compilation, I run:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/myclose.so
```

Then I run:

```
cat myclose.c
```

The output I get is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int close(int fd) {
    printf("Closing fd: %d\n", fd);
    return 0;
}
Closing fd: 3
```

Yay! Works right? Almost. `cat` calls `close()` more than once, but we only see one line of output. According to `strace` (and common sense), `close()` should be called for file descriptors 1 and 2 as well. If I run `cat *` and cat all the files in the directory, I see "Closing fd: 3", "Closing fd: 4", etc. up to the last file in the directory. Since all of these file descriptors are greater than 2, I thought maybe there was an issue with closing the special file descriptors (stdout and stderr). However, when I run `ls` I only see the regular output and no "Closing fd:" lines, which means it didn't work for `ls` either, even though `strace` shows `close(3)` when running `ls`.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: I might be completely wrong here, but isn't the shell taking care of FD 1 and 2? Have you tried launching a shell preloading it with your "close()"?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of "replacement" only works for dynamically linked programs.

Any program being linked statical to the library implementing the `close`-call would fail to have it "replaced".

The latter will be the case for each call to `close()` out of the library implementing the orginal `close()` itself. And it also seems to be the case for the standard file descriptors `0`, `1`, and `2` as their closing most likely is implemented in the same library, that is in the libc implementation in use.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised it worked as well as it did!

You are replacing the C library entry for close(), not the system call.  However, other parts of the C library are still being used for those programs.  Probably there is some direct linkage to the first 3 file handles.  Have a look at the source of whichever C library you are using.